# Nesting a List in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a new list for each value in `list1` and nest the results but struggling to get from `list1` to `desired_result`.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
desired_result = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension like so:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
desired_result = [[x] for x in list1]
print(desired_result)
# [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `desired_list` as a new empty list.  Then iterate over `list1` and make a new one-element list from each item, and append it to `desired_list`.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
desired_result = []

for item in list1:
    desired_result.append([item])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
desired_result = [[x] for x in list1]
```